# whenever i m click on spinnerfield the value increases of spinnerfield i want dynamically change the value of textfield value

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

In that code i want to whenever click on the spinnerfield the value increases of spinnerfield that time dynamically change the value of textfield value.

```
Ext.setup
({
    icon: 'icon.png',
    tabletStartupScreen: 'tablet_startup.png',
    phoneStartupScreen: 'phone_startup.png',
    glossOnIcon: false,
    onReady: function() 
  {

new Ext.Panel
({

  fullscreen:'true',

      items:[
              {   
                 xtype  : 'spinnerfield',
                 name:'sp',
              width:'20%',
                  height:'13%',
              minValue: 0,
              },
             {
               xtype:'textfield',
                   name:'price',
               height:'13%',
                   width:'8%', 
                   html:'<b>350</b>',
           }

    ]

});

 }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 events you can listen to: 'spin', 'spindown', 'spinup'.
Reference: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Spinner-event-spin

First change "new Ext.Panel" to "var myPanel = new Ext.Panel" so you can access your panel to get the textfield and change its contents.

Then implement the eventlistener for your spinnerfield:

```
{   
    xtype  : 'spinnerfield',
    name:'sp',
    width:'20%',
    height:'13%',
    minValue: 0,
    listeners: {
        spin: function(thisSpinner, numberValue, directionString) {
            // Get the text field:
            var textField = yourPanel.items.get(1);
            // Update the text field:
            textField.setValue("your new value");
        }
    }
},
```